# android - webview does not open pdf or ms-word

Tags: android, pdf, webview

My webview does not want to open pdfs or word docs after loading html pages.
if I start the app url string with a pdf or a word doc it opens fine, but If I start with html then from there clicked on a pdf or a word link, nothing happens...

What am I missing?
Do I have my code in the right place? why is it only working on load. Is my code only execute once on create and then it gets ignored? Do I need a listener or something to apply my if statement when a link is clicked to find out to load the url or myScript? How do I keep updating url and myScript values on navigate?

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        String url ="http://example.com/index.html";

String myScript ="https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url;

        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //browser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        browser.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


        if (url.contains(".pdf")){
            browser.loadUrl(myScript);
        } else if (url.contains(".doc")){
            browser.loadUrl(myScript);
        }else{
            browser.loadUrl(url);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (browser.isFocused() && browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Exit!")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

and in my manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label=""
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and activity main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have no idea why you are passing `application/pdf` to `loadData()`, since `myScript` does not contain PDF, but rather HTML. Then again, I do not recommend this approach (relying on a Google Docs URL) for showing content in the first place. For PDFs, download them and show them in the user's chosen PDF viewer. Or, in a pinch, use [a real PDF-viewing approach](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: You are right about the loadData, it is part of older code I was trying. but even if I change it to loadData(myScript,"text/html", "UTF-8"); or used the loadUrl and passed the pdf url or combine it with google viewer, I still get no response.